# How to match the first left brace of a document using a regex

Tags: json, regex

I have a document from which I would like to match the first left `{` of that whole document using regular expression. I tried this `{{1}` but it match all the first left braces of the whole document on different lines. I would like to match only the first one of the whole documents. How should I go about this?

Comment: Would `({)` not work - if it's matching the whole document, sounds like you're using the `/g` global flag when you shouldn't be

Comment: Two options. Disable global matching (as @Light mentioned) so that it only matches once. Or use `^(.*?){` or `^([^{]*){` and replace with `$1` (or `\1` in some languages). It would help if you mentioned the language/regex engine you're using. In .net you can use `(?<=^[{]*){` and replace with empty string

Answer (score 0):

use this regex you will get your output:

```
{+?
```

i have tested it online

screenshot:

[image: Online Regex Testing]